# How to extract MP4 seekpoints information from PHP/FFmpeg/MP4Box/Anything?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4

Is it possible to extract the seekpoints/keyframes from a MP4 file in the following fashion:

Keyframe - Time Range (in seconds) - Offset (in bytes)

Example:
0 - 0s - 77262

1 - 0.5s - 144183

2 - 1s - 222965

3 - 1.5s - 293303

4 - 2s - 362199

5 - 2.5s - 431178

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffprobe`. Perhaps something like this:

```
ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=key_frame,coded_picture_number,pkt_pts_time,pkt_pos input.mp4 | grep -A 3 "key_frame=1"
```

Results in:

```
key_frame=1
pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pkt_pos=48
coded_picture_number=0
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts_time=10.000000
pkt_pos=47130
coded_picture_number=250
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts_time=20.000000
pkt_pos=92713
coded_picture_number=500
--
key_frame=1
pkt_pts_time=30.000000
pkt_pos=138159
coded_picture_number=750
```

- `key_frame=1` indicates that the particular frame is a key frame.
- You may have to choose `section_entries` if this example does not give you exactly what you want. See `man ffprobe`.
- See the `-print_format` option to change the output printing format (default, compact, csv, flat, ini, json, xml). You may have to perform additional processing to get what you want.